# Extracting numbers from string using field calculator of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I need to move number values one field to another field in ArcMap. There's no need to move any alphabetic string vales.
Like attached picture shown having number values too so I want those number values only into ADDR_NUMB field, What is the query for this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: im tried a adding field as double, but itsn not working while doing field calculate

Comment: No, I meant which expression you were using to populate that field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def extract_number(adr):
    numberlist = [i for i in adr if i.isdigit()]
    if len(numberlist)>0:
        return int(''.join(numberlist))

extract_number( !Adress!)
```

[image]